# How to configure source code generation using node and webpack?

Tags: node.js, webpack

I have a project that uses webpack for the browser, and node.js for tests.

Now it [turns out](https://github.com/ajv-validator/ajv/issues/406) that I need to generate a `validator.js` source file from a `schema.json` (JSON Type Definition) file that the other `.js` source files can import.

How do I most cleanly integrate this with both webpack and node.js? I'd like to not have to think about it: The js file should get created if it is missing and re-created *only* if the `schema.json` file changes (== is newer).

Here is
**`package.json`**:

```json
{
  "name": "my-chrome-extension",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "description": "My Chrome Extension",
  "type": "module",
  "scripts": {
    "watch": "webpack --mode=development --watch --config config/webpack.config.cjs",
    "build": "webpack --mode=production --config config/webpack.config.cjs",
    "test": "mocha",
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    ...
  },
  "dependencies": {
    ...
  }
}
```

Had it been an old `Makefile`, it would have been super easy, but how do I do that with `package.json` and `webpack.config.js`?

Ideally, it should work for both the node.js based mocha tests and for `webpack --watch`.

I could create `scripts.pre(watch|build|test)` rules that all generate the source file "if needed", but that is so ugly and won't work for `webpack --watch`.

Surely there must be some elegant way to do this, since it was so incredibly easy when using a **`Makefile`**:

```
src/generated.js: path/to/schema.json
    generate-schema-validtor -in path/to/schema.json --out src/generated.js

build: src/generated.js
    webpack --mode=production --config config/webpack.config.cjs

test: src/generated.js
    mocha
```

(But then `Makefile`s don't really have `--watch`)